# Run macro with a change to a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently able to change the range of a Active X spinner("*Device1*") based on the current date and time. Time determining the row number and date determining the column number. Cells(B3:H3) return dates using the Today() function and Cell(A3) returns the current time every 10 seconds. I've utilized the Offset() function but I now realize the spinner value needs to reset to 0 each time variable fDate or fTime has changed. These are the Subs I'm currently working with. Ideally I'd like to be able to call on *Sub SpinnerReset()* only if the fDate and fTime have changed from their previous values to avoid resetting the value every 10 seconds.

Maybe a way to retain previous values and compare/run if not equal? I'm not sure if that's possible.

```
Sub Device1_Change()
Dim fDate, fTime As Integer
'Change fDate based on day'
    If Range("B3") = Date Then fDate = 0
    If Range("C3") = Date Then fDate = 16
    If Range("D3") = Date Then fDate = 32
    If Range("E3") = Date Then fDate = 48
    If Range("F3") = Date Then fDate = 64
    If Range("G3") = Date Then fDate = 80
    If Range("H3") = Date Then fDate = 96
'Change fTime based on TimeStamp'
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("09:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("11:00:00") Then fTime = 0
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("10:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("12:00:00") Then fTime = 1
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("11:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("13:00:00") Then fTime = 2
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("12:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("14:00:00") Then fTime = 3
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("13:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("15:00:00") Then fTime = 4
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("14:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("16:00:00") Then fTime = 5
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("15:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("17:00:00") Then fTime = 6
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("16:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("18:00:00") Then fTime = 7
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("17:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("19:00:00") Then fTime = 8
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("18:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("20:00:00") Then fTime = 9
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("19:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("21:00:00") Then fTime = 10
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("20:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("22:00:00") Then fTime = 11
    If Range("A3") > TimeValue("21:59:59") And Range("A3") < TimeValue("23:00:00") Then fTime = 12

'Select cell for spinner'
Worksheets("Count").Range("C4").Offset(fTime, fDate).Value = Device1.Value
End Sub

Sub SpinnerReset()
Device1.Value = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know when `fDate`or `fTime` has changed?  Are you looking to see if any cell in `B3:H3` changes, and that updates `fDate`?

Comment: The current format with fDate and fTime works fine. The cell effected by the spinner changes with the update to the current time and date, but the main issue is once a new cell is being effected the spinner still carries over the previous value. I would like the value of the spinner to reset once the the cell it's effecting has changed. If you know of a simpler format to change the effected cell I'm open to ideas.

Comment: Which cells will change, and when they change, do you want the macro to re-run on?

Comment: **Updated the original post for more clarification** The cell moves across a separate sheet within the same workbook for the purpose of recording data _sheet2(C4:DJ16)_  .The macro I'd like to re run is `Sub SpinnerReset()` but only if the change in `fTime` and `fDate` is different from it's previous value to avoid losing data every 10 seconds when the Range("A3") updates.

Comment: If I read that correctly, `fDate` and `fTime` will only change if `Device1_Change()` is run **and** the values in `A3` and/or `B3:H3` have changed too.  Would another way to look at this be "If a cell in range `B3:H3` *or* `A3` changes, then re-run the macro to update `fDate` and `fTime`,  which then updates the cell offset by `fTime` and `fDate`?

Comment: Since the only thing you really care about is the current date (no need to keep track of the time), you'll want to have a cell somewhere that has the last known date in it, and then compare against that cell when you change the spinner.  If the date has changed, run the SpinnerReset and update the storage cell.

Comment: @tigeravater If the hour has changed the cell selected will change and requires the value of the spinner to be set back to zero. The same instance applies when the date has change. You're correct @BruceWayne the problem is `fTime` responds to the current time on the users computer, which is checked every ten seconds. I think I need to store the previously determined value of `fTime` and compare it to the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, your code would look something like below.  Please note that I just made up a sheet name (Storage) and cell (A1).  It could be anything you want, and you could keep that sheet hidden if preferred.

**EDIT**: Condensed the `fDate` and `fTime` code, and also included the Hour in the Storage cell.

```
Private Sub Device1_Change()

    Dim fDate As Long, fTime As Long

    'Change the sheet and cell to wherever you store the date
    'Note that the date will be stored as an Excel datecode
    With Sheets("Storage").Range("A1")
        If .Value <> Format(Now, "dd/mm/yy hh") Then
            SpinnerReset
            .Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yy hh")
        End If
    End With

    fDate = Evaluate("16*(MATCH(TODAY(),B3:H3,0)-1)")
    fTime = Evaluate("FLOOR(A3,1/24)*24-10")

    Sheets("Count").Range("C4").Offset(fTime, fDate).Value = Me.Device1.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: I see where your going with it. I think you're right I might have to run updates to `fDate` and `fTime` in a seperate sub if they are going to be responsible for calling `Sub SpinnerReset()`. I'm not sure how that would look.

Comment: @AvidAdventurer `fDate` and `fTime` wouldn't change, I just didn't type it out.  It would be put in the spot `'Rest of your code here`

Comment: @AvidAdventurer I condensed your `fDate` and `fTime` assignment code, and also included the Hour in the storage cell. See edited answer.